# UITextview Keyboard doesn't allow to press "send" button

Tags: ios, keyboard, textview

I started programming something like a Chat App and during that I got this little problem:
I started implementing a Textview (for the user to write messages), which works fine. If I press into the Textview, the keyboard shows up and I can write some text. The button, which can the user press if he want's to send the message, is in a View. So if I press on this button, the keyboard first fades down, and no message will be send. So the action of the button will not be called. I want the send button to work, even when the keyboard is shown. So if I press the send button, the keyboard should scroll down and the message should be send to the server.
Maybe someone knows a clue, why this is happening.

Thanks,
Tobias

---

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([messagesend isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != messagesend) {
        [messagesend resignFirstResponder];
    }
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]){
            [textView resignFirstResponder];
            textView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, textView.contentSize.height-textView.frame.size.height);

        }
    return YES;
}

- (void) keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [note userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    CGRect frame = messagesendview.frame;
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y-(kbSize.height);

    CGRect frame1 = _myTableView.frame;
    frame1.size.height = frame1.size.height-(kbSize.height);

    NSNumber *durationValue = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = durationValue.doubleValue;


    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
        messagesendview.frame = frame;
        _myTableView.frame = frame1;
    }];

    if (_myTableView.contentSize.height > _myTableView.frame.size.height)
    {
        CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, _myTableView.contentSize.height - _myTableView.frame.size.height);
        [self.myTableView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)note
{

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [note userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    CGRect frame = messagesendview.frame;
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y+(kbSize.height);

    NSNumber *durationValue = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = durationValue.doubleValue;

    CGRect frame1 = _myTableView.frame;
    frame1.size.height = frame1.size.height+(kbSize.height);


    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
        messagesendview.frame = frame;
        _myTableView.frame = frame1;
    }];

}
- (IBAction)send:(id)sender {
    [messagesend resignFirstResponder];
    [self sendmessage];
    }
```

I think my problem is in the touchesBegan method. Basically I'm trying to recognize when the user presses outside the messagesend (TextView). But the Button "Send" is outside, too...

Comment: does scroll down the keyboard mean you want to hide the keyboard ?

Comment: What is your problem i didnt get actually? Keyboard hides the button?

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]){
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        //Here u can call your "send message" method
        return NO;
    }else{
        return YES;
    }
}
```

OR:

```
- (IBAction)yourSendButton:(id)sender {
    [self.yourTextView resignFirstResponder];
    [self sendMessage:self.yourTextView.text];
    self.yourTextView.text = @"";
}
```

Comment: But if I will use the first version, the user isn't allowed to press return, without sending the message, am I right? Return should stay return.

Comment: This does not work for me. The same problem appears again. With your code example my keyboard fades down if I press return for a second time. I also tried the other code with resigning the first responder, but this doesn't work, too. So basically my send-Button has no reaction if I press it, while the Keyboard is up. I tried a NSLog, to write something in the console, when the method get's called, but it will first be called, when it press a second time on the button and the keyboard already faded down.

Answer (score 1):

Write you code of send message in delegate method of `UITextView.`

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

  if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
  {
   /// Call method OR write code of send message
    return NO;
  }
  else
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. This method will call several times during editing

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are well.

The thing is I met with this problem and it took time to figure out the best solution.

UITextView does not response for sendButton event as UITextField's :

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyType.send {

        //--> here to delegate the function of the sending
    }
    return true
}
```

So if you want to use the Sending button as well, just implement
textView.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyType.send

and after

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

//if the user tap on return button(or send button) that will lead a line break
        if textView.text.contains("\n") {

```
        //clear text and resignfirstresponder
        textView.text = ""
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Bests,